# Average frequency vs average period

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, frequency, oscillators

Suppose I have two oscillators with frequencies $f_1$ and $f_2$ and periods $T_1=\frac{1}{f_1}$ and $T_2=\frac{1}{f_2}$, respectively. The average frequency is thus $f=\frac{f_1+f_2}{2}$ and average period is $T=\frac{T_1+T_2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{1}{f_1}+\frac{1}{f_2}\Big)$. However, $T \neq \frac{1}{f}$, which is clear to me mathematically but intuitively displeasing. Which of the two (if any) is a more informative measure of "average" for the oscillators? Are there any intuitive ways to reconcile them? Is this even a reasonable question to ask?

Comment: I think this happens because $T=1/f$ is not a linear relation while averaging is a linear operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're just different types of average.  There are [lots of different ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average#Summary_of_types) of averaging numbers, which are useful for different things.  The arithmetic mean of periods is equivalent to the [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) of frequencies and vice versa.

Comment: A useful addition is that you can get the desired relationship $\bar{T} = \left(\bar{f}\right)^{-1}$ if you use the geometric mean $\bar{x} = \left[\prod_{i=1}^N x_i\right]^{1/N}$ for finding both averages. It's easy to write out longhand for $N=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Which one is the "more informative" number depends on the physics that you try to describe.

Side mark: Theodor Hänsch pointed out, that you should always try to measure frequencies instead of time intervals. You might want to watch his [nobel lecture](https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2005/hansch-lecture.html)